# Devise find_for_authentication not firing with multiple authentication keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have two devise models: User and Member

As such, I'm specifying authentication keys on the models themselves instead of in the Devise initializer.

Member.rb

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
    :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable, :authentication_keys => [:email, :subdomain]
```

I also override

```
  def self.find_for_authentication(conditions={})
    debugger
    conditions[:account_id] = Account.find_by_subdomain(conditions.delete(:subdomain)).id
    super(conditions)
  end
```

Unfortunately, when authentication_keys has multiple keys, my find_for_authentication method doesn't appear to be firing.  Works fine when I specify just one key.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

subdomain should have been a request_key since it's part of the request.

```
request_keys => [:subdomain]
```

Comment: It is true that subdomain should have been a request_key.  However, you don't need authentication_keys at all for find_for_authentication to work, and you will still be able to access the subdomain from conditions.